# How to save data with dynamic names using save() in R

Tags: r

I tried to save a bunch of data in dynamic names using `save()` but got an Error:

> objects ... not found.

It looks that `write.csv()` works well. Can you help on `save()`?

```
names <- c('JOHN', 'ADAM')  
dummy <- "FamilyName "
for (name in names)  {
    names[name] <- paste(dummy, name)
    write.csv(names[name], paste(name, ".csv", sep=''), row.names=F)
    save(names[name], paste(name, ".Rdata", sep=''), row.names=F)
}
```

Comment: I'm doing the same sort of task at the moment. Since you are saving one object at a time, you might want to look into `saveRDS`.

Comment: `save(list = character()))` for characters.  Also,  for safety, you should name all your arguments in `save`, because the first one is `...`.

Comment: Also, you could simply do `x = names[name]` and then feed x to `save` on the next line (notice I name the "file" argument) `save(x, file = paste(name, ".Rdata", sep=''), row.names=F)` Additionaly consider `saveRDS` / `readRDS` for single objects, they may be more convenient (ok, thanks Frank for pointing that out:).

Comment: saveRDS works. Thanks Frank!

Comment: Thank you all! saveRDS() works well on single object. Any way to save data with multiple columns/variables using the value of the looping variable as name (JOHN, ADAM) of each data object? For example, dummy has more variables in data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be updating the vector that you are looping through.  If you modify the code to use a temp variable instead of writing to names, your code works:

```
names <- c('JOHN', 'ADAM')  
dummy <- "FamilyName "
for (name in names)  {
  outStr <- paste(dummy, name)
  write.csv(outStr, paste(name, ".csv", sep=''), row.names=F)
  save(outStr, file=paste(name, ".Rdata", sep=''), row.names=F)
}
```